# Application Data Folder Could Not Be Created - Visual Studio (2008/2010)

Tags: visual-studio

From looking through lots of questions I can see quite a few other people have experienced this problem. Upon opening Visual Studio (2008 & 2010) I get the error message: The Application Data Folder Could Not Be Created.

I have tried all kinds of things; registry fixes, AppData folder fixes and a lot of other things that StackOverflow, Microsoft forums and Google have suggested.

Anything that you could suggest would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Maybe you could add a bit more detail about your system? We know each other IRL and you told me you had general permission problems on your system. Try adding any details you have, it all helps you to get an answer. And welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

After you've fixed the registry entries for the AppData folder, make sure you reboot as DJ Were-Panda suggests on [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/5d55ca96-3b8f-4510-bb77-ca0e45aa17cc).

Answer (score 0):

I did following to fix this issue when it came up. not sure will help in your case, 
http://tutewall.com/application-data-folder-for-visual-studio-could-not-be-created/